# Environment Variable Not recognised

Tags: java, operating-system, java-7

I am setting Environment Variable, Still OS cant recognise. Check this out you will get it.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/raqr4wbtoxxz0b8/1.JPG

I tried with Admin privileges also still same but when I enter

```
echo %java_home%
```

or

```
echo %jre_home%
```

It is showing path corretly. Why isnt javac command working.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have `javac` in your path. Setting the `JAVA_HOME` and/or `JRE_HOME` environment variables (which aren't needed any more, for the most part) does nothing to the `PATH` which the command shell uses to find executables.

Put the relevant JDK `bin` directory in your `PATH` environment variable instead - and unless you actually *need* `JRE_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` for some reason, I'd get rid of them. If you *do* need them, get rid of the "bin" part - it should just be the root JRE directory, e.g.

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45
```

Comment: I m running Tomcat Server but when I am starting Tomcat, its showing me error:The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctl
This environment variable is needed to run this program.

Comment: @Jax-L: You may need it for Tomcat - but you didn't mention Tomcat anywhere in your question. That comes under "for some reason" in my answer. And the value of the environment variable is inappropriate anyway - I've edited my answer to indicate that.

Comment: Thanx a lot! really appreciate your help! :) But I didnt get Why %PATH% is defined for javac. I mean how 'path' variable name is recognised by javac & not 'JAVA_HOME'. It gives same path? Can u post any link which explain this?

Comment: @Jax-L: The path is how the `javac` executable is found in the first place. It has nothing to do with Java specifically - it's just part of the command shell. If you'd written the full path to javac explicitly in the command shell, you wouldn't have seen that issue (but it would have been a pain).

Answer (score 2):

Your path `JAVA_HOME` should be, for example

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk.1.7.0_45
```

And your `Path` variable should be

```
...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
```

`javac` is in the `bin` folder which should be on your path.

Answer (score 2):

That has nothing to do with Java environment variables.

When you type `javac`, or any other command, Windows will search the folders in the `%PATH%` environment variable to find an EXE file with that name.

You need to add your JDK directory to `%PATH%`.

You also need to restart cmd to pick up the changes.

Comment: Thank You. But Why Windows does find PATH variable for javac command?

Comment: @Jax-L: Because you never put it there.

Answer (score 0):

You must restart `cmd` for new variables to be picked up. And java `bin` folder needs to be included in `path`. When you type `javac` it goes through all folders defined in `path` to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Include the JRE/JDK path in `System variables->PATH` as well

After adding path varaibles,restart the cmd